# Could not launch app No such file or directory

Tags: xcode

My app had been working fine until I decided to rename my Xcode Project. It will not let me launch the app now, it just gives the no such file or directory message. I have tried to go to organizer and delete the derived data, but it doesn't give me the option to. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try by cleaning the project?

Comment: Yes I cleaned it, deleted the app, reinstalled it, and manually deleted the derived data folder.

Comment: Try by restarting the xcode

Comment: Ok I think what happened is I changed something in the plist that it didnt like, I changed everything back and now it works, its kinda weird